# How can I check a given link if href is clicked or not? And count the clicks per user?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

admin adding details to user contains code that will be keyword to search in the url page, link which should click by user.

[image: image description]

```
<TD> <%= rs1.getString(1) %> </TD>
       <TD> <a target="_blank" href="youtube.html?value=<%=rs1.getString(2)%>" onclick="UrlController"><%=rs1.getString(2)%></a>
```

Here my link unable to call servlet.
            `<TD> <%= rs1.getString(3) %> </TD>`

Comment: do you have any backend process that are able to count the clicks per user ??

Comment: Add more details.

Comment: i just have no idea what variable i should use to get count of clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScpript for checking if the link is clicked:

```
 $("YourId").click(function(){
   alert("yes link clicked");
 });
```

And if you want pure JavaScript:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); 
  for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    if (elements[i].className == 'YourId') { 
      elements[i].onclick = function(){ 
       alert("yes link clicked); 
      }
    } 
  }
```

Comment: if i want to search keyword in the link. please suggest some code. urlconnection code suitable for it?